# C, BMP processing...no clue :/

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

I am supposed to read in a .bmp file and then alter it based on command line arguements.

Examples:
-fromrow x, where x specifies the bottommost row to process
-torow x, where x specifies the topmost row to process
-fromcol x, where x specifies the leftmost column to process
-tocol x, where x specifies the rightmost column to process
-op x, where x is one of the following
   -- 1= threshold the image(any pixel value in the specifies range over 127 is changed t0 255, and pixel values 127 or less is changed to 0)
   -- 2= negative (any pixel value p in the specified range is changed to 255-p)

I have been given this code as am example of reading a .bmp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp= fopen("sample.bmp", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL){
            printf("Error");
    }

    int temp=0;  

    //Go to Byte 22
    fseek(fp,22,SEEK_SET);
    //Read byte 22 into an integer variable
    fread(&temp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("Number of Rows: %d\n", temp); 

    fseek(fp,18,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&temp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("Number of Columns: %d\n", temp); 

    fseek(fp,10,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&temp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    printf("Start of Pixels: %d\n", temp); 

    fclose (fp);
}
```

What is "Start of Pixels"? I suppose I somehow loope through the bytes of the image and copy them into a 2D array...but I don't know the suntax for accessing the files bytes?

I don't even know where to start in terms of altering an image... :/ I'm at a loss.
ANY help/advice/linfo/links would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start by reading in a [`BITMAPFILEHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374.aspx), then a [`BITMAPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375.aspx) (which contains a [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx)). These will give you the information necessary to find and interpret the pixels.

Comment: Ok, so I know the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` contains information about the BMP file itself (height, width), but how do you read its contents? The example code uses `fseek(fp,22,SEEK_SET);` But how did they get that?? where is the byte `22` coming from? I can't find any information about reading IN a BMP file and then manipulating it. Only creating one.

Comment: Assuming you're doing this on Windows, you'd normally just want to define a BITMAPFILEHEADER structure, then use fread to read from the beginning of the file into that.