# How to read a BMP file in Visual C++ and extract width, Height and data with a example

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, bitmap

Iam completely new to C++ but I am a pro in image processing  using MATLAB

Iam looking for a header file (ex: CImg.h )which can read BMP and retrieve length width and 2d array similar to 'imread' function in MATLAB... i am not allowed to use Opencv Opengl

An example would help
TIA

Comment: Checking wikipedia found http://www.kalytta.com/bitmap.h

Comment: The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure is declared in the standard Windows header files. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array