# Iterating through the pixels of a .bmp in C++

Tags: c++, bmp

NOTE: I changed the title from .png to .bmp due to a comment suggesting bitmaps instead.

I'm making this simple 2d grid based CMD-game, and I want to make .png levels and turn them into level data for my game.

So basically all I want to know is, how would I iterate through the pixels of a bmp to parse it to some level data.

This is how I did it with a .txt

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string str;
while (std::getline(file, str))
{
    x++;
    for (char& c : str) {
        y++;
        updateTile(coordinate(x), coordinate(y), c);
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any helpful threads so I posted this new one, hope I'm not breaking any rules

Comment: Do you mean *layers* in a PNG format?

Comment: PNG files are in no way comparable to text files. You should lookup for a suitable image processing library, that is capable of the `.png` format.

Comment: To say that reading pixels directly out of a PNG is non-trivial would be an understatement. What you want to do is load the PNG into a native bitmap format and manipulate that.

Comment: Have you searched the internet for the PNG file format?

Comment: Alright I can make the levels as bitmaps. Now how would I manipulate bitmaps?

Comment: You haven't really stated what sort of data you plan to put in your image.  Is it black and white?  8-bit color?  24-bit color?  BMP is an easy format to read.  The spec is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format and you can find examples all over, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still want to read png-files, but if you do, check this decoder:
http://lodev.org/lodepng/

It loads a png-file into a vector where 4 chars (bytes) give one pixel(RGBA format). So by loading 4 chars at once, you will get one pixel.

I haven't used it before, but it looks easy to use.