# Read "bitmap" pixels in c++

Tags: c++, bitmap, pixel, scanning

Well I have a problem . I need to change a bitmap.bmp color into black and white using c++ , but the problem is I don't know how to read and change pixels .
I don't know a bit about how to read a bitmap file . what library should I include? how should I work with pixels after scanning them ?
I tried searching the web but I didn't find what I was seeking.
any help would be appreciated ...
I really need this information ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array may help you.  The [bmp file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is pretty simple to work with.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in order to read bitmap u can use this and save .bmp bits as char to a vector(for example)...

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char bit;
   vector<char> name;

   while(cin.get(bit))
   {
       name.push_back(bit);
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this give access to individual pixels?

Comment: Every pixels are saved in one of the vectors elements as char, if u know that pixel adress u can easily access it.

Comment: Yes, *if* you know that, which will require correctly interpreting the header and probably also the color table...