# How to convert TIF image to char array in c++

Tags: arrays, bitmap, c++-cli, tesseract

I'm working with tesseract ocr.I have done it by console. But during GUI of C++ I faced some problem.  In console I have used char array to get input image. But now I'm uploading an image by openFileDialog. I need to convert it in char array. But giving many error. I'm giving my code which is written under a recogition button. How can I solve my problem? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array). It's not helpful for me.

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
             char image[256];
             //cin>>image;//while I'm taking input in console
             image=im;//im is the bitmap image which I have loaded.
             PIX   *pixs = pixRead(image);

             STRING text_out;
             api.ProcessPages(image, NULL, 0, &text_out);

            //cout<<text_out.string();
            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open ("example.txt");
            myfile << text_out.string();
            myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read BMP pixel values into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751749/how-can-i-read-bmp-pixel-values-into-an-array)

Comment: May be not. That was a console problem.