# Read BMP pixels and write to console

Tags: c++, windows, image, bmp

I was reading [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744950/6360521) to try to read manually the pixels inside a bmp file. I didn't really understand how to actually print the pixels of the image to the console? In the main function, to print the first, second, third,... pixels of the image I should replace "?" by what in the following?

> cout << buffer[?] << endl;

**code**

```
#pragma pack(1)

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include "bmp.h"

vector<char> buffer;
PBITMAPFILEHEADER file_header;
PBITMAPINFOHEADER info_header;

void fill() {
    std::ifstream file("test.bmp");

    if (file) {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        streampos length = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        buffer.resize(length);
        file.read(&buffer[0], length);

        file_header = (PBITMAPFILEHEADER)(&buffer[0]);
        info_header = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)(&buffer[0] + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
       
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    fill();

    cout << buffer[0] << buffer[1] << endl;
    cout << file_header->bfSize << endl;
    cout << info_header->biWidth << " " << info_header->biHeight << endl;
    unsigned char* start = (unsigned char*)(&buffer[0] + file_header->bfOffBits);
    cout << start[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In bmp.h i have defined structures:

```
#pragma once

typedef int LONG;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
  WORD  bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  WORD  bfReserved1;
  WORD  bfReserved2;
  DWORD bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize;
  LONG  biWidth;
  LONG  biHeight;
  WORD  biPlanes;
  WORD  biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression;
  DWORD biSizeImage;
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed;
  DWORD biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Comment: Can you show a more complete program instead of making us follow a trail and then interpret what you did?

Comment: the buffer contains headers and the pixel data. You replace `?` with the index and consider that the pixel data starts at some offset

Comment: In general you can't display an image on a console.  You need to open another window and display your image in that, and it's not a simple process at all.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, yes its just I am not sure of the size of the offset. I tried `unsigned char* start = (unsigned char*)(&buffer[0] + sizeof(char)*(file_header->bfOffBits))` or `char* start = (unsigned char*)(&buffer[0] + file_header->bfOffBits)` but it didn't work

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes I don't want to print the image on the console, just the value of the pixels

Comment: then please edit the question to add missing details, make it selfcontained. You seem to be using code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744950/4117728. And you seem to have some code with an issue, but we can only help you with the code when you show us the code and explain the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: Well, the offset is only part of it. It depends on the pixel format too, and compression if the BMP uses that.

Comment: What @paddy said.  Do you need to read *any* bitmap, or just one particular one?  Do you have any control over the source of these bitmaps?

Comment: You should look into [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) instead of trying to read the file yourself.

Comment: @Mark Not true, the console supports graphics and you can display images. Sadly the functions are undocumented.

Comment: I found what was not right. I am not sure why but I had to write `std::ifstream file("test.bmp", std::ios::binary);` instead of `std::ifstream file(filename);` otherwise I would have a lot of zero added between the header and the data.